how can I use ui jetpack compose in an existing web project?
I have a set of ui components using jetpack compose. I want to use them in an existing web project.
How can i do this?
Is it possible to configure a kmp project for a wasm target and make it a library that can be plugged into a web project? can I use my components there?
I will be grateful for any ideas and especially examples of successful cases. my task is to use android/compose ui in a web project.
I haven’t found how I can do this through kotlin js and as I understand it, it’s more for logic and use together with html/css
I also know that I can use kmp + cmp and configure web applications, but this does not work for me

Kotlin Wasm is still in alpha, some of the api may not work properly so far now, you can more explore it on here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/wasm-get-started.html#what-s-next

You can see an example of how to use jetpack compose components on the web in my project where I collect various architectural and technological solutions in a branch with a multiplatform:
https://github.com/TarasovVP/Android-Architecure-Templates/tree/kmp_implementation
If you have more specific questions - feel free.
